# SQL Developer Error "Required property 'hostname' cannot be null or empty" when creating new database connection

Tags: sql, ssh, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to connect to one of my company's databases through SSH, however I run into this error where it shows:
 Required property 'hostname' cannot be null or empty
[image: Error]

This connection was created manually and the SSH host is already set up, any ideas of what could be causing this error?

Comment: can you add some details even masked? Otherwise will be very difficult to help you!

Comment: Pick a port fwd... basically you're going to talk to 1521 on localhost and it will get fwd to the remote end of the ssh tunnel

Comment: I have added a port forward to my SSH Host and am now getting an IO: Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection, the port forward is to localhost port 1521.